# How to add another "for" loop in bash shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Bash shell script.sh polls the network range for target OIDs, changes the 4th octet `10.46.32.x`.
I want to extend the range of poll, include the 3rd octet `10.46.x.x`

How to add another *"for"* loop for 3rd octet?

```
#!/bin/bash
# snmpget command poll the network range for certain OIDs

for (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do 
    host=10.46.32.$i; 
    snmpget -v 2c -c public -t 0.5 -r 1 $host iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2; 
done;
read -p 'press Enter to continue...'
```

Edit: 2 loops

```
#!/bin/bash
# snmpget command poll the network range for certain OIDs

for i4th (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do 
for i3th (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do
    host=10.46.$i3rd.$i4th;  
    snmpget -v 2c -c public -t 0.5 -r 1 $host iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2; 
done;
read -p 'press Enter to continue...'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking for a nested `for` loop, how about simply defining one inside? Also you can use the brace expansion instead of the traditional C-style loop

```
for octet4th in {254..1..1}; do
    for octet3rd in {254..1..1}; do
        host=10.46.$octet3rd.$octet4th
    done
done
```

By doing `{254..1..1}`, you don't need to write a full length traditional loop, it just works by reducing one at a time (the last `1`) up-to the value `1`. You could try running a simple test by doing `echo {10..1..1}` to get a hold of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Inian's cool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50525600/8868289), if you for some reason would prefer C-style loops:

```
for (( i4th=254; i4th; i4th=i4th-1 )) do
    for (( i3th=254; i3th; i3th=i3th-1 )) do
        host=10.46.$i3th.$i4th
        snmpget -v 2c -c public -t 0.5 -r 1 $host iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2
    done;
done;
```

And also note, that you don't need to use `$` sign inside arithmetic expansion operators.